# Слайдер в QTableVidget и QTableView

Tags: qt, c++

Подскажите, как можно сделать так, что бы элементы QTableView или QTableWidget нельзя было изменять вручную, но при этом был активен слайдер (полоса прокрутки)?
Если сделать так

```
ui->tableViewResult->setDisabled(true);
```

слайдер становится неактивным (им нельзя пользоваться, его видно, но он статический)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
ui->tableViewResult->setEditTriggers(QAbstractView::NoEditTriggers);
```